# ¿Cómo saber si un String contiene algún caracter especial? Como @,?,.,!, etc. ¿Existe alguna función en JAVA para eso parecida a Character.isDigit?

Tags: java

Aquí les muestro una pequeña parte del código que he tratado de usar.
Ya está revisado si la contraseña tiene mayúsculas, minúsculas y números, faltan los caracteres especiales.

```
Public static boolean contraSegura(String password){ // Esta seria la funcion boolena
    if(password.length()>=8){
        char c;
        boolean minuscula = false;
        boolean mayuscula = false;
        boolean digito = false; 
        boolean especial = false;
        
        for(int i=0;i<password.length();i++){
            c=password.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isUpperCase(i)) mayuscula = true;
            if(Character.isLowerCase(i)) minuscula = true;
            if(Character.isDigit(i)) digito = true;
            if(Character.is) // Faltaria revisar si tiene algun caracter especial
        }


    } else {
        return false;
    }



}
```

Comment: mmmm si no es letra y no es digito....será un "carácter especial"?

Comment: ¿Y qué sería un carácter especial? ¿Un carácter de una lista previamente confeccionada por ti? ¿O qué criterio usarías para averiguarlo? Incluso qué operación matemática o condición debería cumplir?

Comment: revisa el uso de [Character.isJavaIdentifierPart (char ch)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/character-isjavaidentifierpart-method-in-java-with-examples/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un ejemplo simple podría ser este:

```
public static boolean Validar(String psw) 
{

    if(psw.length()>=8)
    {
        Pattern letras = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z]");
        Pattern numeros = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
        Pattern especiales = Pattern.compile ("[!@#$%&*()_+=|<>?{}\\[\\]~-]");

        Matcher letra = letras.matcher(psw);
        Matcher numero = numeros.matcher(psw);
        Matcher especial = especiales.matcher(psw);

        return letra.find() && numero.find() && especial.find();

    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar expresiones regulares para verificar si tienes algún caracter especial, en este caso usa el metodo matches de la clase string junto con expresiones regulares para que verifiques si el String cumple con los patrones.
El for para que verifiques si el caracter no es una letra ni un digito utilizado, si se encuentra uno que no es letra ni digito se establece la variable especial como true.
Y tambien verifica que todas las condiciones son true para determinar si la contraseña cumple con los requisitos de tener al menos una minuscula, mayuscula, un digito y un caracter especial.
Todo esto solo verifica si hay almenos un caracter especial en la contraseña. pero si quieres verificar si todos los caracteres son especiales, puedes modificar la condicion en el bucle for y ajustarlo a lo que quieres.

```
public static boolean contraSegura(String password) {
    if (password.length() >= 8) {
        boolean minuscula = false;
        boolean mayuscula = false;
        boolean digito = false;
        boolean especial = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            char c = password.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                mayuscula = true;
            }
            if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                minuscula = true;
            }
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                digito = true;
            }
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                especial = true;
            }
        }

        return minuscula && mayuscula && digito && especial;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias!! me ha sido de utilidad.